# Confused about Python code (Beginner)

Tags: python

I've come across a question that I was confused about so decided to look it up. However, I'm a bit confused as to what some of the functions do in the code. The question was 'write a function to get rid of duplicate letters'

```
def remove_duplicates(s):
result = ""
dic = {}
for i in s:
    if i not in dic:
        result+=i
        if ord(i.lower()) >= ord('a') and ord(i.lower()) <= ord('z'):
            dic[i] = 1
return result

print(remove_duplicates("bookkeeper"))
```

I'm a bit confused as to what the purpose of the result = "" and dic = {}? I've never seen this before so no idea how it works.

And what does result+=i mean? And finally I have absolutely no idea what's going in the if ord line. Ord is something I just learned an hour ago so I have no idea how it's interacting with i.lower and 'a' / 'z'.

Comment: I think ord is unnecessary you could just use `if i.islower()`

Comment: I am not entirely sure if this is an on-topic question here on [so]. I think you should learn the basics of python before asking a question here.

Answer (score 2):

`result = ""` creates a variable named `result` and initializes it to a blank string.

`dic = {}` creates a variable named `dic` and initializes it to an empty dictionary.  (Dictionaries are special Python objects.)

`result += i` is shorthand for `result = result + i`.

The `if ord` line is ensuring that `i` is a letter between A and Z.  (Although this seems a very roundabout way to do it.)

Perhaps you should spend some time with a basic Python tutorial?

Comment: I've looked around however I can't quite find any that is absolutely basic (Maybe I just suck at looking for them), most that I've seen or read include other words that I don't quite understand yet.

Answer (score 1):

`result = "" and dic = {}` initallize the variables result as an empty string ans dic as a dictionary.

`result+=i mean` === `result = result + i`

About the ord() it checks if i.lower is in "range" of a - z